# Firebase Crashlytics Custom Log Only Log Single Line

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

Recently my app has been crashing while trying to deserialize the JSON sent from the server and unfortunately the server doesn't record any log so I can't verify with them. So I decided to log the JSON response for this particular Api, I know that it's a bad practice to log server response but it's the only way I could try to identify the issue, the response for this api is not that long so I think it should be fine.

The issue comes in when I tried to reveal the log and found out it only shows one line in the firebase console as below:

`raw  response : {`

The result I was expecting were something as below,vit shows up nicely in the debug console while developing using CLSNSLogv. I thought it will be the same in firebase console too but it was not the case.

```
raw response : {
        success ={
            Status = OK;
            Object1 = "test"
            Object2 = "test2"
        };
    }
```

Below is the code for logging, "value" is a dictionary as below:

```
value: [String : AnyObject]?
CLSLogv("raw response : %@", getVaList([value!]))
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the response to JSON using [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) and then remove all the carriage returns so that it's all one line. If you log that modified value it should appear correctly in the Crashlytics logs.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was on holiday. Will try and get back to you !

Answer (score 1):

This is a Crashlytics issue, my team has been experiencing this issue lately. We were printing dictionary using CLS_LOG in ObjC and we've noticed that it displays only first line of the dictionary.

I've contacted Crashlytics support team, and a guy from there confirmed a bug and told me that he contacted their engineering team for a fix.

You can change the way of logging for now to display everything in single line, or log by log, or you can wait for a fix.

Comment: Good to know that but since I need a quick fix, I went for Alexizamerican's answer. Thanks buddy !